# Can the expected value of a random variable be viewed as a particular linear transformation?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, linear-transformations, expected-value

I teach a low-level probability and statistics class, and today, part of our discussion was of a couple of well-known properties that the expectation obeys. Namely, for random variables $X$ and $Y$ and a constant $a$, $E(aX) = aE(X)$ and $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$.

A student who is also enrolled in a Linear Algebra course then recognized these properties as the same properties one asks for to get a linear transformation.

Thus, I'd like to know if one can view the expected value as a linear transformation from a vector space of random variables to $\mathbb{R}$. Is this an already-studied notion that's out there ? Perhaps one can link me to a source that might contain a discussion on this, as well.

Thank you !

Comment: Integration is a linear operator, so is expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Call the underlying probability space $\Omega$ and for simplicity let's assume that all random variables are real-valued.  Then as your student pointed out, the map $X \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X]$ is a linear transformation from the vector space $V = \{ \text{(measurable) functions } \Omega \to \mathbb{R} \}$ to the vector space $\mathbb{R}$.  The space $V$ has a very natural vector space structure.

(I put "measurable" in parentheses because whether or not you want to talk about that depends on the level of the probability course you're teaching)